Help promote the site via the offical Stack Exchange social network profiles!
Stack Exchange has special social network profiles for each site (like our @StackCogSci on Twitter), but they also have "parent" accounts for the whole SE network, and they have a process for advertising questions on those accounts.
Basically how this would work is we'd find Good, answered, questions that give a good, understandable impression of our site and content, and subit the question via this official form. Since these would be shared with all of the Stack Exchange network's followers, try and pick something relatable to a general audience with a good answer rooted in format science. We want to give the impression that there's real, relatable questions out there we're answering with authoritative answers and sources.
Note that you can share Cog Sci's content at any time with your friends on Twitter/Facebook/ect. Try and pick targeted, easily relatable content. If you've got friends/colleagues that are researchers, throw them one of our answered research level questions. 

can we only submit question that have answers? I think it would be great to have a mix of accessible questions with solid answers (to attract eyes) and good open technical questions to attract new users.

@ArtemKaznatcheev I don't know SE's policy or generally what they tend to share, but I assume they share more answered posts just so everyone can have a good read. The Twitter accounts have a separate "Can you answer this?" message though to indicate "hey, this question doesn't have a good answer yet"

Great idea. Thanks for sharing the process. I'll be sure to submit a question or two.

Great idea. And here's the result of my attempt to share the leg jiggling question:
7 plus ones and a share:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/101120115153580954446/posts/X7y2d4v3ASD
I'm not sure what other networks it was shared on.

I was about to ask, does it only go to Google plus or is it also on Facebook? Looks like the SE twitter bot is automated only.
